# Can a webapp restart aborted webjob?

Tags: azure-webjobs

I have a blob-triggered webjob running in the free tier. As expected the webjob aborts after some time (15-20 minutes) which I'm told is the "price" we pay for using the free tier.

The only way a blob can arrive on the container is through a request to the corresponding web site, so just before uploading the blob can I have the webapp restart the aborted webjob somehow?

Comment: not sure if what you are asking is possible, but rather than having a blobltrigger (wihch required a continous job and to have always on) you can create a scheduled job so that every  X minutes you check if there are new blob. Also there is a know issue on blobtrigger :http://stackoverflow.com/a/36489192/4167200.

Comment: Yes, but the blob-triggered ones seem to work best when freshly restarted.  So I'm wondering if after the web app pushes up a new blob it could check the status and if the webjob has aborted, to restart it somehow.   I'm trying to stay in the free tier.  To use the scheduler at any reasonable (high-frequency) schedule you'd have to use the paid tier.